# how to get non interactive text output with gcloud help command

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to get help pages for gcloud commands without the less prompt.  For example

```
gcloud help
```

Generates a help page with a `:` prompt for navigating the output.  This is great for interactive use, but sometimes I am in a tool and I will the tool to navigate the output.  My tool gets hung up on the prompt.

I've tried

- -q | --quiet option

```
gcloud -q help
```

- --format=text option

```
gcloud --format=text
```

- --format=none option

```
gcloud --format=none
```

None of these techniques remove the interactive prompt.  Also, if the above options are not for removing the less pager, what/how are they used?

Comment: You can write the output of “gcloud help” to a text file and read the contents from the file.

1. gcloud help >>ghelp.txt
2. cat help.txt

Comment: that would be more complex than what I have already suggested below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do this, but it seems like one of the options would preclude this necessity.

```
gcloud --help | cat
```

Comment: I haven't gotten an answer.  I assume this is the best available solution/method so I am marking it as solution to remove warning in my activity feed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution that will save you a sub-process

```
PAGER=cat gcloud --help
```

or

```
export PAGER=cat
gcloud --help
```